# Search within folders in Google Drive

Tags: directory, google-drive-api

Is it possible to search within a google drive folder using gdrive developer sdk?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is entirely possible!

When listing files with [drive.files.list](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/list), you can provide [search query parameters](https://developers.google.com/drive/search-parameters). A query like:

```
'MYFOLDERID' in parents
```

will search for files in the folder with ID `MYFOLDERID`. There are more details about other query parameters and searching in general in the linked docs.

Comment: Can you please give an example for HTTP/REST?
I have tried `https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files?q: name contains 'note'` but it's not working